# Cookies aren't working in my website, they are enabled in my browser

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hi guys I've been trying to have this code work for a while now, I checked if my cookies were enabled on http://www.whatismybrowser.com/are-cookies-enabled, and they are working.
Any ideas as to why this code isn't working for me?

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="delCookie">DELETE COOKIE</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#delCookie").click(function(){
        del_cookie("cookie");   
    });

    console.log(document.cookie);
    var visit = getCookie("cookie");
    if (visit == null) {
        alert("First popup");
        var expire = new Date();
        expire = new Date(expire.getTime() + 7776000000);
        document.cookie = "cookie=here; expires=" + expire;
    }
});
function del_cookie(name)
{
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    } else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include jQuery - insert it in your head tag!

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
```

And that's all there is to it, through common sense and (I admit) using a console.

Comment: @user3308265 You have to mark the answer that worked as correct.  To do this, press the white checkmark outlined by a black outline